# How can I install a driver using devcon for a driver built on the host machine?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, driver, devcon

Is it possible to install a driver that I built on my local machine? I don't have a second device that I can deploy to.

Comment: If you are using Windows Pro you can install a Virtual Machine and test install your Driver in the virtual machine.  If you don't have Windows Pro  you can download something like VirtualBox and and use that as the VM manager.

Comment: @RichardCritten Is there really no other option for installing the driver? Any resource for how to set up virtualbox and deploy to it?

Comment: One error in your driver code and you have BSOD your development machine - this is not good.  VirtualBox has a complete instructions on its website https://www.virtualbox.org/

Comment: Also use the Microsoft Driver Verifier - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/driver-verifier